# How to tab to next field in Gmail without accepting smart compose

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gmail

To send an email in Gmail, I use the tab key to switch focus to the 'send' button and then press enter. However, this conflicts with smart compose, which uses tab to accept the suggested text. I don't want to disable smart compose entirely, I just want to be able to send an email with the keyboard without accepting smart compose suggestions. How do I do this?

[image: Unwanted smart compose suggestion in finished email]

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two ways:

- Easiest: use `ctrl+Enter` to send instead of `Tab Enter`. This shortcut works even if you have keyboard shortcuts turned off in Gmail's settings. If this combination doesn't work for you you can [set a custom shortcut](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6594?hl=en#).
- Alternative: use one of the arrow keys to move the cursor off the end of the sentence. The smart compose suggestion will disappear and you can use `Tab Enter` as usual.